# Store countByKey result into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I want to count the number of IndicatePresence messages for each user for any given day (out of a Cassandra table), and then store this in a separate Cassandra table to drive some dashboard pages. I managed to get the 'countByKey' working, but now cannot figure out how to use the Spark-Cassandra 'saveToCassandra' method with a Map (it only takes RDD).

```
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> indicatePresenceTable = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "indicatepresence");
    JavaPairRDD<UserDate, CassandraRow> keyedByUserDate = indicatePresenceTable.keyBy(new Function<CassandraRow, UserDate>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public UserDate call(CassandraRow cassandraIndicatePresenceRow) throws Exception {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return new UserDate(cassandraIndicatePresenceRow.getString("userid"), sdf.format(cassandraIndicatePresenceRow.getDate("date")));
        }
    });

    Map<UserDate, Object> countByKey = keyedByUserDate.countByKey();

    writerBuilder("analytics", "countbykey", ???).saveToCassandra();
```

Is there a way use a Map directly in a writerBuilder? Or should I write my own custom reducer, that returns an RDD, but essentially does the same thing as the countByKey method? Or, should I convert each entry in the Map into a new POJO (eg UserDateCount, with user, date, and count) and use 'parallelize' to turn the list into an RDD and then store that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to never return the result to the driver (by using countByKey). Instead do a reduceByKey to get another RDD back in the form of `(key, count)`. Map that RDD to the row format of your table and then call `saveToCassandra` on that.

The most important strength of this approach is we never serialize the data back to the driver application. All the information is kept on the cluster and saved from their directly to C* rather than running through the bottleneck of the driver application.

Example (Very Similar to a Map Reduce Word Count):

1. Map each element to (key, 1)
2. Call reduceByKey to change (key, 1) -> (key, count)
3. Map each element to something writeable to C* (key,count)-> WritableObject
4. Call save to C*

In Scala this would be something like

```
keyedByUserDate
  .map(_.1, 1)                               // Take the Key portion of the tuple and replace the value portion with 1
  .reduceByKey( _ + _ )                      // Combine the value portions for all elements which share a key
  .map{ case (key, value) => your C* format} // Change the Tuple2 to something that matches your C* table
  .saveToCassandra(ks,tab)                   // Save to Cassandra
```

In Java it is a little more convoluted (Insert your types in for K and V)

```
.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<K,V>,K,Long>>, Tuple2<K, Long>(){
    @Override
    public Tuple2<K, Long> call(Tuple2<K, V> input) throws Exception {
      return new Tuple2(input._1(),1)
    }
}.reduceByKey(new Function2(Long,Long,Long)(){
    @Override
    public Long call(Long value1, Long value2) throws Exception {
      return value1 + value2
    }
}.map(new Function1(Tuple2<K, Long>, OutputTableClass)(){  
    @Override
    public OutputTableClass call(Tuple2<K,Long> input) throws Exception {
    //Do some work here
    return new OutputTableClass(col1,col2,col3 ... colN)
   }
}.saveToCassandra(ks,tab, mapToRow(OutputTableClass.class))
```

Comment: Ah ok that was what I was thinking - so basically if I find the source code for 'countByKey' and put that in my own custom function for 'reduceByKey', but keep it as an RDD instead of letting it call 'mapAsSerializableJavaMap', that would be ok?

Comment: Thats the idea, the reduceByKey should just be a ( _ + _ ) kind of lambda

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to this and I'm confused by the reduce - for an RDD<K, V> the reduce takes in <V, V> and returns V. Does that mean that to do a count, my V class has to include a count field inside itself (presumably which will be hardcoded to 1 until the reduce is run)? In the case where my V is a CassandraRow, presumably I will have to create a wrapper like CassandraRowWithCount and use this in my RDD? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I'm adding more details in the question

Comment: Ahh, the map returning (key, 1) was the bit I couldn't figure out - great answer, thanks for the help!